# command line error when trying to use java package

Tags: java, linux

I'm learning java packages in school and I'm able to create and use my package on netbeans perfectly but cannot do it from the lubuntu command line. I get an error: could not find or load main class. Here is the code but I know this is not the problem since it works perfectly in netbeans

```
    package animals;

    public class MammalInt implements Animal
    {

     public void eat()
     {
      System.out.println("Mammal eats");
     }

     public void travel()
     {
      System.out.println("Mammal travels");
     } 

     public static void main(String args[])
     {
      MammalInt m = new MammalInt();
      m.eat();
      m.travel();
     }
    } 


     package animals;

     interface Animal 
     {
      public void eat();
      public void travel();
     }
```

I first compile `Animal.java` and put the `Animal.class` file into a directory 
animals. I then compile `MammalInt.java`. If I do not put the `Animal.class` file in a animals directory it will not compile `MammalInt.java` . After I have both class files into the animals directory I do `java animals/MammalInt` and get the error: cannot find or load main class. I also have doe java `MammalInt` and get the same error. This is really frustrating. Please help.

Comment: Show how do you call the `java` statement.

Comment: What are you entering on the command line? Which is the current working directory relative to the one containing the class file?

Comment: the class file is in my current working directory    leo@leo-VirtualBox:~/Documents/Spring2015/CSC220/Practice/Packages/animals$

Comment: Try running the command with the Packages directory as the current working directory.

Comment: java animals/MammalInt

Comment: I do not know the answer, but just a tip, you don't have to say that a method in a interface public is, because it's default is public so

    void eat();
    void travel();

is goed enough.

Comment: Patrica, thank you so much. I can finally get some real work done now. You are lifesaver. It worked. I would like to know why though.

Comment: Gillian, you are right. Thanks for the reminder. This is my first time using interfaces. Its my second java course (data structures), we did not do any interfaces in my Intro course. But you are right. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When compiling (a set of files) you need to use the path.So use `/`

```
javac animals/*.java
```

When running the Java class, you need to specify the Java name of the class.

In your case this is done as follows:

```
java animals.MammalInt
```

This says you want the class `MammalInt` in the package `animal`. Depending on your installation you also need to add your current directory to your classpath (this is where java looks for `.class` files), resulting in:

```
java -cp . animals.MammalInt
```

Note that you run all commands from the `root` of your source code tree. This means the directory that contains the directories for your packages. So if you have the following direcotries:

```
project/
project/animals/
project/animals/Animal.java
```

Then run the commands from the `project/` directories.

Comment: `this  is a test` just checking how to format my comments to look like code